# A result about Fredholm operator

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, fa.functional-analysis

When I read the article "Index Theory" in [Handbook of global analysis](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=02-sWUXs798C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Handbook+of+Gobal+analysis&source=bl&ots=q7vsTpaaBz&sig=Y-VJ07SLaAw-YWct-3LLb_qWs_Q&hl=zh-CN&ei=RzR1TKn1DYaKuQO7z8mHBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false), I meet a result as below(Corollary 2.13):

If every $F_0\in \mathcal {F}(H_1,H_2)$, there is an open neighborhood $U_0\subseteq \mathcal {B}(H_1,H_2)$, such that $F\in U_0$ implies $F((KerF_0)^\perp)\oplus F_0(H_1)^\perp =H_2$

I didn't find this result in other books.
I can't understand the proof about it.  $Fv+w=F(v-f_0)+w$? Why?

Edit: 
$H_1$ and $H_2$ are separable Hilbert spaces.

$\mathcal {F}(H_1,H_2)$ is the spaces of Fredholm operators.

$\mathcal {B}(H_1,H_2)$ is the spaces of bounded operators.

In the proof, construct a $\overline{F}:H_1\oplus F_0(H_1)^\perp \to H_2\oplus kerF_0$ by 
$\overline{F}(v,w)=(Fv-w,\pi_{KerF_0}v)$, this is a isomorphism. Since $\overline{F}$ is onto, for any $(u,\ f_0)\in H_2\oplus kerF_0$, there is $(v,w)\in H_1\oplus F_0(H_1)^\perp$, with $u=Fv-w$ and $\pi_{KerF_0}v=f_0$.

$\pi_{KerF_0}: H_1\to KerF_0$

Comment: While it is probably obvious for people in the field, you should really define all your notations why asking a question on MO. Just so that readers don't have to guess that you meant $\mathcal{F}$ to be the Fredholm operators and $\mathcal{B}$ to be the bounded operators. 

Comment: ... I meant "when" instead of "why" above, of course. 

Comment: I agree with Willie. The question should be reformulated so as to clarify all the notations used.

Comment: Thanks, Willie Wong and André Henriques, I edit my question.

Comment: And what is it that you don't understand? The only slightly non-trivial step I see in your sketch of the proof is the fact that $\bar{F}$ is an isomorphism. Once you have that, picking $f_0 = 0$ you see that every element of $H_2$ can be written as $Fv + w$ where $v\in H_1$ and $w\in F_0(H_1)^\perp$. On the other hand, by definition $\bar{F} |_{(ker F_0)^\perp\oplus F(H_1)^\perp}$ clearly has range contained in $H_2$. Hence your corollary. 

Comment: If you need to deal with the action of Fredholm operators on closed subspaces and so, I recommend you the notion of *Fredholm pais of linear subspaces*. You may find an account of the subject in Kato's book. 